# How can I find a command block on a realm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I was playing on a realm and someone hooked up a redstone clock to a command block that clears command blocks from your inventory, and I was not amused.

I can't find it! D: I want to delete the command block so we can do teleport links around the realm but we cannot find it anywhere.

Any realm friendly methods of searching for command blocks in an area?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following to replace all command blocks in a hundred block radius from you:

```
/fill ~50 ~50 ~50 ~-50 ~-50 ~-50 air 0 replace command_block
```

Do this a few times all over the map.

Comment: A 100x100x100 box is not 100 block radius...